# tmux in xterm - next-window no refresh (text from one window in the next)

Tags: tmux, xterm

using tmux, when switching windows the content of one window is taken to the next window.

To reporoduce:

```
tmux new; 
C-b c; # (create new window)
ls /bin;
C-b n; # (go to next-window)
```

Now the content of the ls output is in both windows.

tmux.conf:

```
set -g set-clipboard off                                                                                                                                                                                            
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L                                                                                                                                                                                       
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R                                                                                                                                                                                      
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U                                                                                                                                                                                         
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D                                                                                                                                                                                       
bind -n S-Left  previous-window                                                                                                                                                                                     
bind -n S-Right next-window                                                                                                                                                                                         
bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1                                                                                                                                                                              
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1                                                                                                                                                                             
bind -n C-h select-window -t 0                                                                                                                                                                                      
bind-key e set-window-option synchronize-panes on \;\                                                                                                                                                               
set-window-option pane-active-border-style fg=red \;\                                                                                                                                                             
set-window-option pane-border-style fg=yellow \;\                                                                                                                                                                 
display-message "Sync panes ON"                                                                                                                                                                                   
bind-key E set-window-option synchronize-panes off \;\
set-window-option pane-active-border-style fg=green \;\
set-window-option pane-border-style default \;\
display-message "Sync panes OFF"
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message " # tmux.conf is reloaded"
set -g status-left '#{?client_prefix,#[bg=colour245 fg=colour233 bold],#[fg=colour155]} (#S)'
```

This is not always, but i can't really identify, when it starts.
I thought, this may be mouse usage related, but it also happens when starting fresh xterm, fresh tmux.

I connect to my xterm using Plink, from Xming under Windows.

Regards

Sören

Comment: It seems like this doesn't happen using gnome-terminal.

Comment: cannot reproduce on mac in alacritty